# Is there a more lispy way to write this code?

Tags: functional-programming, coding-style, clojure

I've been learning Clojure, and since I come from a Ruby, and before that Java background, I have trouble thinking procedurally.

Is there a more 'lispy' way to write this code, or is this ok?

```
(defn foo
  ([s t]
     (let [x (+ 4 (- t s))]
       (if (> 2 (if (> 6 x)
                  x
                  6)
              x)
         x
         2))))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In clojure, like in any other language, it is usually best to use built-in functions whenever applicable. So since clojure has a `min` and a `max` function, so you can replace your `if`s with:

```
(max 2 (min 6 x))
```

If those functions did not exist in clojure's standard library, I would have recommended defining them because putting the logic for `min` and `max` into their own function leads to much nicer code than having it all in the `foo` function.

Comment: @Dan: Ehrm, no it doesn't. If `x` is less than `2`, `(min 6 x)` is `x`, while `(max 2 (min 6 x))` is `2`. So it's hardly the same thing.

Comment: @seppk2k: Gaack, you're right. I'm deleting that comment. Sorry.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I will have to dive deeper into the built-ins to see what's available. Thanks for the pointer. :)